# Unable to RSA-encrypt correctly a token in Java

Tags: java, encryption, base64, rsa, httpurlconnection

Good morning to everyone!

All the following are programmed in Java, using HttpURLConnection.

I am making a program in Java which needs to be connected with a server.
The server needs to see a token from my app so that will accept me to connect with their resource-entity I want to access.

This token I have to sent must be encrypted in RSA algorithm, and it must encoded to Base64.

Imagine that the server agrees to sent tokens like this:
"92992925:01/01/2017:00:00:00" which has date and hour which has to be constructed dynamically...
After this token has to be encrypted in RSA and Base64.

I tried to do it with a lot of solutions in google, but nothing worked...
The encrypted token was like: "[B@825828282", and not like "f44fd55de...5bb5c43==", so server gives me 404 http error (unauthorized)

Can someone give me a solution which works please?

Thanks for your patience

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the code that you wrote for base64 encoding

Comment: [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)